# CakePHP HABTM relations listing

Tags: cakephp, model, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm have quite a problem while trying to make a list (for the admin section) of HABTM relations. Here's the deal:

permissions: id, name;
users: id, username;
permissions_users: permission_id, user_id

`Permission HasAndBelongsToMany User`

I want to make a listing like such:

`User.id | User.username | Permission.id | Permission.name

1 | Jack | 1 | posts

1 | Jack | 2 | comments

2 | Mark | 1 | posts

3 | Kate | 3 | tags`

Stuff like: `$this->Permission->User->find('all');` (or the other way around) doesn't really work, because it will fetch many permissions for `Jack`, also the other way around it will fetch many users for the `posts` permission, thus making it impossible to list in the view.

What I want is to get a array like:

`[0] = > array(

[User] => array([id] => 1 [username] => Jack)

[Permission] => array([id] => 1 [name] => posts)

)

[1] = > array(

[User] => array([id] => 1 [username] => Jack)

[Permission] => array([id] => 2 [name] => comments)

)
...`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to use the `foreach` and loop through your result to reconstruct a new array like that.

```
$user = array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'Jack');
$data = array();
foreach($permission as $per) {
   $data[] = array($user, $per['Permission'])
}
```